# Is there a better way to handle the cookie/redirect

Tags: php, cookies, mobile, redirect

I have put together a mobile website for us, and have the main site, madisonstudios.com, redirecting to the mobile site, madisonstudios.mobi, if the device is a mobile device.

I also put a full website button on the mobile site, and when the referrer is the mobile site, it sets a cookie, but I had a problem with still having it redirecting on the first click to the full site, and then once you clicked it the second time it went to the full website.

To solve this issue I added a variable of `$setcookie` and set it to 1, so to make it skip the  redirect. My code below.

I think this is a kind of messy way to do this, and think that there has to be a cleaner way, does anyone have a suggestion that would make sense for me to use. Am I going about this the right way?

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://www.madisonstudios.mobi/" || $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://madisonstudios.mobi/")
{
    setcookie('fromMobi', true, time()+3600*24);
    $setcookie = 1;
}

if ($_COOKIE["fromMobi"] == 1 || $setcookie == 1)
{

} else {
    $uamatches = array("midp", "j2me", "avantg", "docomo", "novarra", "palmos", "palmsource", "240x320", "opwv", "chtml", "pda", "windows\ ce", "mmp\/", "blackberry", "mib\/", "symbian", "wireless", "nokia", "hand", "mobi", "phone", "cdm", "up\.b", "audio", "SIE\-", "SEC\-", "samsung", "HTC", "mot\-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony", "alcatel", "lg", "erics", "vx", "NEC", "philips", "mmm", "xx", "panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch", "rover", "pocket", "benq", "java", "pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi", "bird", "compal", "kg", "voda", "sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", "sgh", "gradi", "jb", "\d\d\di", "moto","webos");

    foreach($uamatches as $uastring){
    if(preg_match("/".$uastring."/i",$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]))
    {
    header('Location: http://www.madisonstudios.mobi');
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Put `exit();` right after your call to `header()` to skip executing the rest of the script and enact the redirect immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
<?php

  // Use stripos() for tidiness, case-insensitivity and ignoring subdomains and paths
  if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'madisonstudios.mobi') !== FALSE) {

    // We came from mobi, set the cookie that says so
    setcookie('fromMobi', true, time()+3600*24);

  } else if (empty($_COOKIE["fromMobi"])) {
    // We only do this if the cookie is not set or it has a value that evaluates
    // to FALSE - empty() does this check for us in one go

    // Look for mobile browsers and redirect them to mobi
    $uamatches = array("midp", "j2me", "avantg", "docomo", "novarra", "palmos", "palmsource", "240x320", "opwv", "chtml", "pda", "windows\ ce", "mmp\/", "blackberry", "mib\/", "symbian", "wireless", "nokia", "hand", "mobi", "phone", "cdm", "up\.b", "audio", "SIE\-", "SEC\-", "samsung", "HTC", "mot\-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony", "alcatel", "lg", "erics", "vx", "NEC", "philips", "mmm", "xx", "panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch", "rover", "pocket", "benq", "java", "pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi", "bird", "compal", "kg", "voda", "sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", "sgh", "gradi", "jb", "\d\d\di", "moto","webos");
    foreach ($uamatches as $uastring) {
      if (preg_match("/".$uastring."/i",$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) {
        header('Location: http://www.madisonstudios.mobi/');
        // If we find one we know we can exit straight away because the user
        // is getting redirected
        exit;
      }
    }

  }
```